# Re-encoding Wav file to AAC LC, AMR WB/NB

Tags: android, wav, aac, amr, re-encoding

Is there any way to re-encode a PCM wav file to another encoding using standard Android SDK?

I can see that is is possible to directly record from the mic into these formats but the app I'm writing has to record in PCM first.
Due to licensing restraints, ffmpeg is not an available option.

---

I now have the following code for Jelly bean but the output is not readable by any media players.

The stage fright code from aosp seems to suggest an mpeg4 container

```
profile.nSampleRate = sampleRate;
profile.nBitRate = bitRate;
profile.nAudioBandWidth = 0;
profile.nFrameLength = 0;
profile.nAACtools = OMX_AUDIO_AACToolAll;
profile.nAACERtools = OMX_AUDIO_AACERNone;
profile.eAACProfile = (OMX_AUDIO_AACPROFILETYPE) aacProfile;
profile.eAACStreamFormat = OMX_AUDIO_AACStreamFormatMP4FF;
```

But the output from the android code is not readable.

The input wav file is 32khz, 16bit signed mono as required.

```
public void doConvert( View v)
{
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            try
            {
                int codecCount = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();

                for ( int i=0; i < codecCount; i++)
                {
                    MediaCodecInfo info = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
                    Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, info.getName());
                    for ( String type : info.getSupportedTypes() )
                    {
                        Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, type);
                    }

                }

                File inputFile = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Media/Report-test5.wav");
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
                fis.skip(44);//remove wav header

                File outputFile = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Media/out.mp4");
                if ( outputFile.exists()) outputFile.delete();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");

                MediaFormat outputFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat("audio/mp4a-latm", 32000, 1);
                outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
                //outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_MASK, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO);
                outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 48000 );
                //outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 64000);
                double durationInMs = (inputFile.length()/64.0)*1000.0;

                outputFormat.setLong(MediaFormat.KEY_DURATION, (long)durationInMs );
                //Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, codec.getOutputFormat().toString());

                codec.configure(outputFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE );
                codec.start();

                ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
                ByteBuffer[] outputBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffers();

                boolean hasMoreData = true;
                MediaCodec.BufferInfo outBuffInfo = new BufferInfo();
                byte readBuffer[] = new byte[64000];
                byte writeBuffer[] = new byte[64000];

                do
                {
                    int nextBuffer = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(1000);
                    logger.log(Level.INFO,"nextInputBuffer = "+nextBuffer);

                    if ( nextBuffer >= 0 )
                    {



                        ByteBuffer inBuf = inputBuffers[nextBuffer];
                        inBuf.clear();
                        int bytesRead = fis.read( readBuffer,0, inBuf.capacity() );
                        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Read = "+bytesRead);

                        if ( bytesRead < inBuf.capacity() )
                        {
                            hasMoreData = false;
                        }

                        inBuf.put(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead );

                        codec.queueInputBuffer(nextBuffer, 0, bytesRead, 0, hasMoreData?0:MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                    }


                    int outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer( outBuffInfo, 1000 );
                    logger.log(Level.INFO,"nextOutputBuffer = "+outputBufferIndex);
                    logger.log(Level.INFO,"outBuffInfo offset = "+outBuffInfo.offset);
                    logger.log(Level.INFO,"outBuffInfo size = "+outBuffInfo.size);
                    logger.log(Level.INFO,"outBuffInfo flags = "+outBuffInfo.flags);


                    //while ( outputBufferIndex > -1 )
                    //{ 

                        outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex].position(outBuffInfo.offset);
                        outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex].get(writeBuffer,0,outBuffInfo.size);

                        fos.write(writeBuffer,0, outBuffInfo.size);
                        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Writing = "+outBuffInfo.size+" bytes");


                        outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex].clear();

                        codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);

                        if ( outBuffInfo.flags == MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM )
                        {
                            codec.flush();
                            codec.stop();
                            codec.release();
                            break;
                        }

                        //outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer( outBuffInfo, 1000 );
                        //logger.log(Level.INFO,"nextOutputBuffer = "+outputBufferIndex);
                    //}

                } while ( outBuffInfo.flags != MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);

                fis.close();
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();



            }
            catch ( Exception e)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, "Codec Error",e);
            }

            logger.log(Level.INFO,"Done");

            return null;
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: Did you make your aac file readable? Can you share it please...?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i'm sure i'm missing some header information but finding what is rather elusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are writing all the generated encoded buffers into a file, but that is missing all sorts of **MetaData** related to the tracks/samples/file etc.

I guess the solutions I can think of is : either you can find a good **muxer** library to write the buffers into the right file format, or you have to wait and see whether the future Android will provide such APIs for you.

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question,

In Android 4.3 and above there is the MediaMuxer class which creates MPEG4 containers for audio and video stream.

```
public boolean encode( File outputFile )
```

{

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 )
{
    try
    {
        mInputWav.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING,"Unable to close Input Wav File ",e);
    }

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Only Available on Android 4.3 and Above");
}

try
{

    int sampleRate = mInputWav.getSampleRate();
    int percentComplete = 0;
    int fileSize = mInputWav.getDataLength();
    int totalBytesRead = 0;

    if ( outputFile.exists()) outputFile.delete();

    MediaMuxer mux = new MediaMuxer( outputFile.getAbsolutePath(), OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

    MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");

    MediaFormat outputFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat("audio/mp4a-latm",sampleRate,1);
    outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
    outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 128000 );

    codec.configure(outputFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE );
    codec.start();

    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffers();

    boolean hasMoreData = true;
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo outBuffInfo = new BufferInfo();
    byte readBuffer[] = new byte[64000];
    double presentationTimeUs=0;
    int audioTrackIdx=0;

    do
    {

        int nextBuffer = 0;
        while ( nextBuffer != -1  && hasMoreData )
        {
            nextBuffer = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(1000);

            if ( nextBuffer >= 0 )
            {
                ByteBuffer inBuf = inputBuffers[nextBuffer];
                inBuf.clear();
                int bytesRead = mInputWav.read( readBuffer,0, inBuf.limit() );

                if ( bytesRead == -1 )
                {
                    hasMoreData = false;                                
                    codec.queueInputBuffer(nextBuffer, 0, 0, (long)presentationTimeUs, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                }
                else
                {

                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;                            
                    inBuf.put(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead );

                    codec.queueInputBuffer(nextBuffer, 0, bytesRead, (long)presentationTimeUs, 0);

                    presentationTimeUs  = 1000000l * (totalBytesRead) / 2 / sampleRate;
                }
            }

        }


        //Drain audio
        int outputBufferIndex = 0;
        while (outputBufferIndex != MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER )
        {
            outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer( outBuffInfo, 10000 );
            if ( outputBufferIndex >= 0 )
            {

                ByteBuffer encodedData = outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex];
                encodedData.position(outBuffInfo.offset);
                encodedData.limit(outBuffInfo.offset + outBuffInfo.size );

                if ((outBuffInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG)!= 0 && outBuffInfo.size != 0) 
                {
                    logger.log(Level.FINE, "video encoder: codec config buffer");
                    // Simply ignore codec config buffers.
                    codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);

                }
                else
                {
                    mux.writeSampleData(audioTrackIdx, outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex], outBuffInfo);
                    codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                }

            }
            else if ( outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED )
            {
                logger.info("Output Format Changed :"+codec.getOutputFormat().toString());
                outputFormat = codec.getOutputFormat();
                audioTrackIdx = mux.addTrack(outputFormat);
                mux.start();

            }
            else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED )
            {
                logger.info("Output Buffers Changed: shouldn't happen on an encode ");
            }
            else if ( outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER)
            {
                logger.info("Encoder Timed Out");
            }
            else
            {
                logger.info("Unkown return code from dequeueOutputBuffer "+outputBufferIndex);
            }
        }

        percentComplete = (int)Math.round(((float)totalBytesRead / (float)fileSize)*100.0);
        logger.info("Percent Complete "+percentComplete+"%");

        if ( mListener != null )
        {
            mListener.onProgressUpdate(percentComplete);
        }

    } while ( outBuffInfo.flags != MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM && !mCanceled);

    mInputWav.close();
    mux.stop();
    mux.release();

    logger.info("Finished");



}
catch ( Exception e)
{
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Codec Error",e);
}


logger.log(Level.INFO,"Done");

return true;
```

}

Comment: what's mInputWav object here?

Comment: mInputWav is just a object that holds info about a wav file.
It is created when the wav is recorded and stored in a db.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a container for it. I prefer adts also, but flv/mp4 works too.

Copy the the payload data into an aray that is large enough for your container, just add on your bits. So after scouring the internet for my solution I worked some snippet into place

```
    profile =( configParams[0]>>3 )&0x1f;

    frequency_index = (this.configParams[0]&0x7) <<1 | (this.configParams[1]>>7) &0x1;

    channel_config = (this.configParams[1]>>3) &0xf;

    int finallength = encoded_length + 7;       
    ENCodedByteArray[0] = (byte) 0xff;
    ENCodedByteArray[1] = (byte) 0xf1;
    ENCodedByteArray[2] = (byte) ( ((profile - 1) << 6) + (frequency_index << 2) +(channel_config >> 2));
    ENCodedByteArray[3] = (byte) (((channel_config & 0x3) << 6) + (finallength >> 11));
    ENCodedByteArray[4] = (byte)( (finallength & 0x7ff) >> 3);
    ENCodedByteArray[5] = (byte) (((finallength & 7) << 5) + 0x1f) ;
    ENCodedByteArray[6] = (byte) 0xfc;
```

Using something like the below, that calls the above

```
            byte chunkADTS[]=new byte[info.size + 7];
            fillInADTSHeader(chunkADTS,info.size);
            outputBuffers[bR].get(chunkADTS,7,info.size);
            buffer.pushData(chunkADTS);
```

Answer (score 0):

The file cannot be played because it does not contain any header information.  A simple(ish) way to make this playable is to add ADTS headers to the raw AAC frames.  You can find a description [here](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=ADTS).

Good luck!